# Create a pong in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pong

I have to create a Pong game using ruby, I also looked at some examples and saw that I need a runtime library to create the game easly (gosu).

My problem is that my project's source code will be pulled and tested by a virtual-machine which has only ruby installed, w/o any libraries/frameworks.

1) Is it possible to download the runtime library w/o install and use it as a local library ?
2) Any suggested library to code a good pong easly for beginners ?

Comment: Homeworks are given to be performed, not stolen / copy-pasted.

Comment: Ruby is not really viable for game development, except maybe like script in some Game engine written in C/C++. I dont think you can make Pong in plain Ruby, without other GFX support libraries you need to install on the machine.
Only option with plain ruby is to write Ruby in combination with Javascript. And the game can run in Web-browser, write logic code in ruby that can run in Sinatra or Rails web application and write Graphics code in Javascript. But that just for demonstration purposes.  If you really in to making a real game, i strongly recommend some other programming languages

Comment: How is the virtual machine going to test a graphical game without graphics?

Comment: @Mudasobwa what u said has just no sens, im just looking for import locally a framework. rip

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://shoesrb.com, it's Ruby GUI Framework

Answer (score 1):

I think this project is good pong for beginner 
https://github.com/subdigital/pong